# Convergence and sum of $S(R,\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5+i\omega}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am looking for a convergence test and a potential analytical expression for this serie:
$$S(R,\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5+i\omega}}$$ Where $R$, $\omega$ are real numbers such that  $0<R < 1$ and $0 \leq \omega \leq \infty$

For the convergence test, I am using the fact that the serie seems to converge by absolute convergence ? since:
$$S(R,\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5}}e^{-i\omega log(4\pi n)}$$
and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5}}e^{-i\omega log(4\pi n)}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5}}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5}}$$ which converge since $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = R$ with $a_{n} = \frac{R^n}{(4\pi n)^{0.5}}$ and $R<1$

Is that correct? I also plotted the complex term up to n = 100 for many values of $R,\omega$ and the sequence always converge.

Now I am clueless on how to calculate the sum. Can the residue theorem be used ?

Any advice are welcome!

Comment: $ S(R,\omega) = (4 \pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}-i\omega} Li_{\frac{1}{2}+i \omega}(R) $, where $Li_s(x)$ is the polylogarithm function.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at literature about this function and did not know that it had so many applications.